# Hosting Angular SSR in github pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular8, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to host angular SSR with github pages? If the backend api is on nodejs/nestjs and no storages are used?

To clarify, we know github pages only serves static sites. But if we had a backend server tagged along with angular project, is it possible to host in github pages after build?

For an example angular SSR with nest js: https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/universal-nest

Comment: I had done it using angular at some point, you have to use the content of dust folder produced by ng build command

Comment: I don't _think_ so, I believe GH pages are static.

Answer (score 2):

gh-pages cant host SSR websites. GitHub pages only serve static content.